# How to connect UIView to Spring and ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I came over this [Spring library](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring) for Swift and in the `README` they tell me to set the View Class as `SpringImageView` in order to have those properties in the `Attribute Inspector`.

What I don't understand is the fact that... I have a `ConnectViewController` already which is linked to the view in the `Storyboard` via that class.

If I want to have those attributes and still have the view linked to my controller, what do I need to do ? I am very new to this. Sorry if it sounds.. wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpringImageView` is a subclass of `UIView` so you can have a `SpringImageView` as a view controller's view. In Interface Builder,

1. select your view
2. bring up the identity inspector (the third icon at the top of the right-hand column or choose menu item View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector or Command-Option-3)
3. enter `SpringImageView` in the `Class` textfield
4. then switch to the attributes inspector (fourth item, or use the menu, or Command-Option-4).

Comment: While both answers are correct, I've chose this one because it's more practically explained and I've seen exactly what's to be done. Thanks again, I have more than enough things to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand. A view controller needs to have a "content view" which is the master view that holds all the other views shown in the view controller.

The only requirement of that view is that it be UIView *or a subclass of UIView*. If a third party library has a custom UIView subclass called SpringImageView, it is still a UIView. It does everything a UIView does, plus more.